# Serious performance problems with Qt5 and X11

Tags: qt5, x11

We ported our application from Qt3 to Qt5. It runs smoothly under Windows but not under Linux (X11). With Qt3 there is no problem with Windows or Linux.

Inside the application there is a canvas of about 1000x800 pixels. A simple vector graphic is drawn onto the canvas. The user clicks into the canvas, holding the mouse button pressed an moves the mouse. Each mouse move results in a repaint.

We registered the milliseconds in each stage:

Start of MouseMove-event handling: 10581

call of update or repaint (makes no difference which one)

Handling of resulting Paint-Event: 10583

Painting finishes: **10584**

return from update/repaint: **10687** (!)

I do not find any reason for this lag of 100ms (at each mouse move event!)

I need help!

Comment: What is your Qt graphics system? If it is `raster`, change it to `opengl` and check for artifacts and performance issues.

Comment: "Each mouse move results in a repaint." Why? Is this by design?

Comment: Each mouse leads by design to a redraw. This was not problem with Qt3. There are just a few hundred or a few thosund vectors involved (a Rhasberry Pi (464 bogomips) with Qt3 does this smoothly) a 64bit x86 (3985 bogomips) is about 10 times slower.). The graphics system might be an issue here (I suppose it is Xrender but I hab no idea how to determine it).

Comment: A I wrote [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161264/is-there-a-way-to-change-configurenotify-event-frequency-in-x11/14161505#14161505), you should not repaint immediately when getting an event. It may not have been an issue before, but it is now. I cannot tell you why, possibly Qt5 increased the number of draw events, it issues qWarning()s it did not before, there's some conversion, other overhead. But I suggest you change your code first.

Comment: The problem is much bigger as I thought in the first place: it is not just the Paint-Event but ANY widget that is realized is VERY,VERY slow. It is almost impossible to use our application through an ssh -X tunnel. Again, the same application only compiled with Qt3 is fast, almost as fast as on a local X-Server. But Qt5 through a tunnel is unusable. The problem is so serious that I cannot ship anyl Qt5-Linux applications and do not use it for testing. All in all Qt5 is as good as dead for Linux. I need a good replacement

Comment: What version of Qt do you use? I have significant downgrade of graphics performance when migrated from Qt 5.4 to Qt 5.5!

Comment: In March we used 5.4, now we use 5.5. 5.4 is by far too slow to be used over ssh -X. We canceled our efforts using Qt and switched to Wx. Qt5 is only usable for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt4.8 the native graphics backend was deprecated.
Remote X11 is no longer drawn with X11 calls but by painting onto a canvas and transmitting the result (a bitmap) to the client. This may result in larger bandwidth requirements and a slower when running X11 over network.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017200/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-amount-of-x11-traffic-produced-by-qt-creator)

Comment: For about 15 months we hoped that this serious bug would be fixed in Qt and installed all version from 5.0 to 5.5. The bug still remains and renders Qt to be unusable for Linux. Our final solution was to quit the Qt5-development for Linux and switch to Wx. Wx is as fast as Qt3.